# endswith() matching?

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I am using the code below to match using `endswith` in Python.

```
while not buff.endswith('/abc #'):
```

But I run into a problem when the line ends as shown below:

```
('console /abc/xyz* #')

('console /abc/xyz/pqrs* #')
```

Now how to match with `endswith` for `"/abc"` anywhere, but `#` must be the last character?

Comment: Should both cases match? How do you define end of line?

Comment: Looks like a good candidate for regular expression `re` module.

Comment: What does "'/abc' must contain in end of line anywhere" mean? Is it a match if the string starts with "/abc"? (Does it matter where "/abc" is?) Note that @martineau just made an edit that removes this phrase from the question, but I don't understand his interpretation either.

Comment: `endswith()` matches only at the end of a string. Sounds to me like you want `if '/abc' in line and line.endswith('#'):`—your question is a little unclear about exactly what cases you want to match.

Comment: Yes "/abc" must contain in the end line and same line must ends with "#"

Comment: kitty: How can it end with two different things?

Comment: say example of end line "apples /abc #" here # is the last charecter of the end line and end line contains /abc so it should match. example2 "apples #" in example2 /abc not exit so it should not match. example 3 "apples# /abc >" in this example # and /abc contains but # is notlast charecter so agin it should not match

Answer (score 2):

I think there's a language barrier here making it hard to understand the requirements, so I'll just propose a solution based on my best guess:

```
while not (buff.endswith("#") and "/abc" in buff):
```

Comment: If the string can be long, it might be better to do the `endswith` test first, since it is O(1).

Comment: @cco Thanks! Swapped.

Answer (score 0):

If the number of paths you're trying to match is small, you can supply a tuple to the `endswith` method.

```
>>> buffs = ["console /abc #", "console /abc/d #", "console /abc/xyz/* #"]
>>> for b in buffs: print(b.endswith("#"))
...
True
True
True
>>> for b in buffs: print(b.endswith("/abc #"))
...
True
False
False
>>> for b in buffs: print(b.endswith(("/abc #", "/abc/d #")))
...
True
True
False
>>>
```

Otherwise you'll need to use a regular expression for your search, e.g.

```
>>> import re
>>> p = re.compile(r"/abc.*#$")  # match "/abc", anything, "#", then EoL
>>> for b in buffs: print(p.search(b) != None)
...
True
True
True
```